# parsing json in Android with different with inner array

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have this json url which outputs this (snippet)

```
{
   "status":true,
   "result":{
      "message":"Successfully retrieved the daily feed.",
      "items":{
         "1376438400":[
            {
               "code":"DjCr3N3o",
               "slug":"soulja-boy-gets-kicked-off-airplane",
               "cdn_screenshot_path":"screenshots\/2013\/08\/DjCr3N3o.png",
               "title":"Soulja Boy Gets Kicked Off Airplane!",
               "hits":"457",
               "date_added":"1376507797"
            },
            {
               "code":"7V9eOVpX",
               "slug":"dr.-dre-and-suge-knight-baby-mama-michelle-surprise-performance-she-sounds-like-a-chipmunk-but-sings-like-an-angel",
               "cdn_screenshot_path":"screenshots\/2013\/08\/7V9eOVpX.png",
               "title":"Dr. Dre AND Suge Knight Baby Mama Michel'le Surprise Performance! (She Sounds Like A Chipmunk But Sings Like An Angel!)",
               "hits":"525",
               "date_added":"1376505010"
            },

            {
               "code":"8ovO203r",
               "slug":"headless-snake-bites-itself-in-the-butt",
               "cdn_screenshot_path":"screenshots\/2013\/08\/8ovO203r.png",
               "title":"Headless Snake Bites Itself In The Butt!",
               "hits":"361",
               "date_added":"1376485812"
            }
         ],
         "1376352000":[
            {
               "code":"9b9jR6qs",
               "slug":"show-you-how-to-do-this-son-chris-paul-hits-4-straight-jumpers-on-colleges-best-point-guards",
               "cdn_screenshot_path":"screenshots\/2013\/08\/9b9jR6qs.jpg",
               "title":"Show You How To Do This Son! Chris Paul Hits 4 Straight Jumpers On College's BEST Point Guards!",
               "hits":"979",
               "date_added":"1376443810"
            },
            {
               "code":"p6l5pwg8",
               "slug":"ttbnez-fck-da-opp-music-video",
               "cdn_screenshot_path":"screenshots\/2013\/08\/p6l5pwg8.png",
               "title":"TTBNEZ - F*ck Da Opp [Music Video]",
               "hits":"316",
               "date_added":"1376419812"
            },
            {
               "code":"haxUoUVt",
               "slug":"strip-life-the-reality-series-feat.-lanipop-entyce-trailer",
               "cdn_screenshot_path":"screenshots\/2013\/08\/haxUoUVt.png",
               "title":"Strip Life: The Reality Series (feat. Lanipop, Entyce) [Trailer]",
               "hits":"426",
               "date_added":"1376419214"
            }
         ],
```

The problem I am having is figuring out how to parse it due to its format and how to reach the data such as "code", "slug" and "title".  This is what I have so far, but it seems wrong as I may have to have 2 loops instead of 1 I think.

This is what I have so far

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array 
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrive JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://api.hoodplug.com/v1/videos/daily_feed?per_page=5&offset=0&format=json");

        try {
            // Locate the array name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("item");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("code", jsonobject.getString("code"));
                map.put("slug", jsonobject.getString("slug"));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("item");` the Array name should be "items" judging by your JSON...

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing a little point here!

in here you got the first json object :

```
 jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://api.hoodplug.com/v1/videos/daily_feed?per_page=5&offset=0&format=json");
```

this json object is the whole big JSON object that contain status and result but you directly want to access the JSON array that inside result object! using this :

```
// Locate the array name
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("items");
```

The right thing is you must get the result object first from the big json object with

```
JSONObject resultObject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("result");
```

then use the resultObject to get the array!

```
try {
            // Locate the array name
            jsonarray = resultObject .getJSONArray("item");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("code", jsonobject.getString("code"));
                map.put("slug", jsonobject.getString("slug"));
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I hope you understand my answer, but if you have other question about my answer feel free to ask! :)